# Blank folder in Git repository, can't remove due to submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I was adding a directory in Git to create a new package. I cloned the `src/` which I was going to include in my repository, and I think I forgot to `rm -rf src/.git`, so somehow post-commit, I have a blank directory with no source, and what appears to be a broken submodule.

I'd like to delete the `src/` folder and re-create the directory and add the source files manually, but I'm getting errors.

`git rm -f src/` gives me:

```
fatal: pathspec 'package/src/' did not match any files
```

Running `git submodule` gives:

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'package/src/'
```

I have no `.gitmodules` file, and I don't want this to be a submodule. I'd just like it to delete this directory so I can re-create it and put the source contents in.

Comment: Have you tried this link-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: I don't want a blank directory, I want to add my source files. But if I add files to src/ at the moment, and do a git add on src, git commit -a does nothing, because it thinks it's a submodule.

Comment: Hey!! just try this command to delete "src" folder. I think it will help you to delete "git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch src" -- --all" . Once deleted, you may use your usual process of commiting your changes.

Comment: That worked. Had to force push obviously!